# Unrecognized VM option 'HeadDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'

Tags: java, android-studio

Всем привет, все работало отлично в Android Studio на Linux, как вдруг я решил залезть в VM Options и вбил куда-то в studio64.vmoptions строчку с настройкой

```
HeadDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```

После перезапуска ПК не запускается студия

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=1024m; support was removed in 8.0
Unrecognized VM option 'HeadDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
Did you mean '(+/-)HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'?
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Видимо я опечатку допустил `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError` (**Heap** вместо head), не найду никак эту строчку, в `studio64.vmoptions` ее нет! Вставлял этот файл из оригинала архива студии - не помогло! Где этот файл создался?

MaxPermSize помню тоже туда писал, но сейчас я вернул оригинальные файлы, откуда читается он?

Comment: Помню как только я выбрал Edit Custom VM Options студия меня что-то спросила (вот, не помню что) но я нажал Create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

studio64.vmoptions был в папке /home/USERNAME/.AndroidStudio3.0 исправил ошибку Head на Heap и студия стала запускаться